# Let X and Y two random independent variables of normal distribution

Tags: probability

Let X and Y two random independent variables of normal distribution, 
with: $\mu_x = 2,\sigma^2_x = 4$, $\mu_y = 3,\sigma^2_y = 9$. 
Let Z = 2X - Y. I know that Z has $\mu_z = 1,\sigma^2_x = 17$. 
I want to calculate $$\mathbb{P}[0 \leq Z < 2]$$

First of all I normalized it: 
$$ \mathbb{P}[-\frac{1}{\sqrt{17}} \leq \frac{Z-1}{\sqrt{17}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{17}}]$$
Then I just call $\frac{Z-1}{\sqrt{17}} = N$, and I need to calculate:
$$ \mathbb{P}[N \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{17}}] - \mathbb{P}[N \leq -\frac{1}{\sqrt{17}}]$$
This is equal to:
$$ 2\Phi(\frac{1}{\sqrt{17}}) - 1$$

I am not sure everything I did is correct, because I get a slight different result from my book, and I want to be sure.

EDIT: $\mu_y = 3$, not 4

Comment: Look against at your $\mu_z$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all we can use the linearity of expectation:

$\mathbb E(Z)=\mathbb E(2X-Y)=2\cdot \mathbb E(X)-\mathbb E(Y)=2\cdot 2-3=1$

Then the variance is $Var(Z)=Var(2X-Y)=2^2Var(X)+Var(Y)=4\cdot 4+9=25$, due independence of $X$ and $Y$.

Therefore $P(0<Z<2)=\Phi\left(\frac{2-1}{\sqrt{25}} \right)-\Phi\left(\frac{0-1}{\sqrt{25}} \right)=\Phi\left(\frac{1}{5} \right)-\Phi\left(\frac{-1}{5} \right)$

Since $W=\frac{Z-\mu_z}{\sigma_z}$ is symmetric around $w=0$, we can also calculate

$P(0<Z<2)=2\Phi\left(\frac{1}{5} \right)-1\approx 15.85\%$